# Cronjob not working(custom module) in windows in magento2

Tags: magento2, cron

I have set my cronjob code and i am running command

> php bin/magento setup:cron:run --group="customgroupname_cron"

but getting below error

> [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]
>
> The "--group" option does not exist.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: It means cron isn't setup in your server you need to setup cron in server

Comment: Can we set it on localhost?

Comment: Yes, you can do it

Comment: Can you please help me .how to set it?

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2, there are three cron jobs required. Because windows doesn’t have cron, we have to use a bat file and configure it to run as a scheduled task as shown below:

Find the location of php.exe – In you have Wamp installed, it’s in Drive:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25 e.g c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25

Go to a folder and create a file named yourcron.bat

Edit this file and paste 3 lines shown below:

in the following file I have added to cron job for re-indexing and cache

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25\php.exe C:\wamp\www\magento2\bin\magento cron:run
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25\php.exe C:\wamp\www\magento2\update\cron.php
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25\php.exe C:\wamp\www\magento2\bin\magento setup:cron:run
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25\php.exe C:\wamp\www\magento2\bin/magento indexer:reindex
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25\php.exe C:\wamp\www\magento2\bin/magento cache:flush
Save the file, open command prompt and enter following command:
```

schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 5 /tn Magento\Cron /tr

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25\yourcron.bat
```

Now click on Start –> Control Panel –> Administrative Tools –> Task Scheduler

Expand Task Schedule Library from the left hand column and click Magento.

Select Cron from the middle pane, click properties from the right pane under selected items.

Under Security Options, click the Change User or Group button.

Now in the current window, enter System username in the object name box and click check names. Click OK to close the User window, and OK to close the Cron properties Window, and close Task Scheduler.

Cron job setup is successful and it will run every 5 minutes.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Current configuration(Run in every 5mins):

1. open your CMD and type `crontab -e command`.
2. add below code

> Cron on server: */5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2
>
> /bin/magento cron:run --group="customapi"

Set you group